# Python regression: Keep all levels in categoricals

Tags: python, regression

I'm using `statsmodels.formula.api` to run a GEE regression. I have categorical and continuous independent variables in the regression and would like that the reference levels in the categorical do not get dropped. `statsmodels.formula.api` appears to by default drop a specific/reference level.

When I look at the "Removing variables" example in the statsmodels [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/example_formulas.html#categorical-variables) I see that the reference levels are included as well, when the formula is of the format below:

```
res = smf.ols(formula='Lottery ~ Literacy + Wealth + C(Region) -1 ', data=df).fit()

print(res.params)

Output:
C(Region)[C]    38.651655
C(Region)[E]    23.223870
C(Region)[N]    28.634694
C(Region)[S]    34.103399
C(Region)[W]    28.560379
```

However, when I run a [GEE regression](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/gee.html) as below, in the same format as the OLS above (including the -1), the reference levels still get automatically dropped from `State`:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.api as sm

fam = sm.families.Binomial()
mod = smf.gee(formula='indicator ~ Income + Unemployment + Debt + C(State) + C(History) -1 ', 'Employee id', data=train_set, family = fam, cov_struct = sm.cov_struct.Exchangeable())
```

I don't know how to go about making sure that the reference levels are kept for the categorical `State` in the GEE model.

Comment: Is one of the other regressors in the gee model also categorical? The `-1` only works for one categorical variable and, AFAIK, we cannot choose for which one.

Comment: @Josef Yes, it does. I edited the question to reflect this. Given this, if I still want to use `statsmodels`, could I just use `statsmodels.api` directly and directly provide the `exog`, with all the reference levels included and without the intercept?

Comment: You can use the models (api) with Dataframe or numpy arrays directly. However, you still have to ensure that you have a nonsingular `exog`.  If you don't drop any reference levels with multiple categorical variables, then the  design matrix will be singular. (That's what patsy and the formulas try to prevent in this case.)

Comment: I'm not sure, but patsy likely chooses the order of categorical variables alphabetically. If you only want `State` to have the full dummy set., then renaming it so that it comes alphabetically before "history" might work.

Comment: @Josef Thanks. However, as per the response [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491420/understanding-which-categorical-variable-has-a-bigger-influence-on-continuous-de) adding multiple categoricals, and keeping their reference levels won't result in the design matrix being singular if the intercept is set to 0. I've been working under the premise that this is accurate.

Comment: @Josef Actually, when I run the regression using the api with the `exog` including all categorical levels and no intercept, the `summary()` still provides coefficients and doesn't give a singularity error

Comment: The answer in that link is misleading. Each full set of dummy variables adds up to 1, row-wise. If there are more than 1 categorical variables, then each adds one implicit constant.

Comment: OLS, WLS, IRLS in statsmodels use by default a generalized inverse. This creates a regularized solution if the exog is singular. However, the cov_params has lower rank and is singular. Most other models will raise an exception if the design matrix is singular.

Comment: @Josef This is extremely helpful, thank you very much. And to your point, if I wanted to determine the main effect of each categorical variable and their various levels, I would then need to regress on the levels of each categorical individually (without the intercept)?